# Busqueda con PIPE y ngx-pagination en angular

Tags: angular, pipe, ngx-pagination

necesito ayuda por favor, tengo una tabla de libros con 12 filas e implemento un busqueda con PIPE y al miso tiempo incluyo una paginacion en donde solo muestre 5 libros, el problema sucede cuando quiero hacer una búsqueda al momento de ingresar el nombre del libro para filtrarlo, solo busca el de los 5 primeros que se encuentran en la paginacion 1, pero no filtra los otros libros de la  siguiente paginacion , solo si le doy clic en botón siguiente me encuentra el libro, como puedo solucionarlo?

PIPE

```
@Pipe({
   name: 'busqueda'
})

    export class BusquedaPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform(libros: Libro[] ,search:string=""): Libro[] {

if(!search){
  return libros
}

const result=[];
for(const lib of libros){
  if(lib.titulo.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase())>-1){
    result.push(lib);
  }
}

return result;

 }
}
```

TABLA CON LA PAGINACION Y EL FILTRO DE BUSQUEDA

```
<tr *ngFor="let lib of libros | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: page}| busqueda:search;let i=index ">
            
              <td style="width: 64px;"><img  src="{{lib.imagen.imagenUrl}}"  class="img-thumbnail rounded"></td>
              <td>{{lib.isbn}}</td>
              <td>{{lib.titulo}}</td>              
              <div class="botonEliminar">
                <a class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="delete(lib)" >
                  <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i>
                </a>
              </div>                
              </td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>              
        </table>
        </div>
        <!--FIN TABLA-->
        <pagination-controls 
        (pageChange)="page = $event"
        previousLabel="Anterior"
        nextLabel="Siguiente "
        ></pagination-controls>
```

Como puedo hacer que filtre todos los datos sin que la paginacion me interrumpa?

Comment: Has probado a cambiar el orden de las pipes? Filtrando primero y después paginando? slds

Comment: Es verdad, muchas gracias, que distraída me siento